# Change Wordpress WooCommerce Product Page Layout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently my Woocommerce product page has a row of social media share icons at the very bottom of my description. I have researched enough to learn how to give it a new priority to move it higher, under the review stars.

What I would like to do, however, is to place it on the same line and to the right of the stars. Could someone more versed in PHP help me with this please?

Thank you for your time!

Here is an image of what I'm trying to do:

http://mommylovestea.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/product-page.jpg

Here is a copy of my current php. This is a Wordpress site running the WooCommerce plugin.Please let me know what else I need to provide and I will do my best to get it.

```
 <?php

    /**
     * The template for displaying lookbook product style content within loops.
     *
     * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-product.php
     *
     * @author      WooThemes
     * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
     * @version     1.6.4
     */


    global $post, $product, $flatsome_opt;

    // Get category permalink
    $permalinks     = get_option( 'woocommerce_permalinks' );
    $category_slug  = empty( $permalinks['category_base'] ) ? _x( 'product-category', 'slug', 'woocommerce' ) : $permalinks['category_base'];

?>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>> 

<div class="row">    
        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_single_product hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_show_messages - 10
             */
             do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product' );
        ?>    
        <div class="large-6 columns product-gallery">        

            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_show_product_images hook
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash - 10
                 * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_images - 20
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );
            ?>

        </div><!-- end large-6 - product-gallery -->

        <div class="product-info large-6 small-12 columns left">
                <?php
                    /**
                     * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook
                     *
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
                     * @hooked ProductShowReviews() (inc/template-tags.php) - 15
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
                     */

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_sharing', 50 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_sharing', 15 );


                    do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
                ?>

        </div><!-- end product-info large-4 -->

<div class="product-page-aside large-2 small-12 columns text-center hide-for-small">

    <div class="next-prev-nav">
        <?php // edit this in inc/template-tags.php // ?>
        <?php next_post_link_product('%link', 'icon-angle-left next', true); ?>
        <?php previous_post_link_product('%link', 'icon-angle-right prev', true); ?>
    </div>

     <?php  woocommerce_get_template('single-product/up-sells.php');?> 

</div><!-- .product-page-aside -->


</div><!-- end row -->


<?php
    //Get the Thumbnail URL for pintrest
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), false, '' );
?>



<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="product-details <?php echo $flatsome_opt['product_display']; ?>-style">
               <div class="row">

                    <div class="large-12 columns ">
                    <?php woocommerce_get_template('single-product/tabs/tabs.php'); ?>
                    </div><!-- .large-9 -->

               </div><!-- .row -->
        </div><!-- .product-details-->

        <hr/><!-- divider -->
    </div><!-- .large-12 -->
</div><!-- .row -->


    <div class="related-product">
        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_single_product_summary hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
             */

            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );

        ?>
    </div><!-- related products -->

</div><!-- #product-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product' ); ?>
```

Comment: Chances are you'll need to float the social media options to the right and the ratings to the left, but without a jsfiddle or link to the site it is going to be hard to help.

Comment: Here is a URL that will get you past the "Coming Soon" page. Thanks for taking the time to help me.

http://mommylovestea.com/stackoverflow

The page I have been working on is here:

http://mommylovestea.com/product/passionberry-fruit-tisane/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following styles should work:

```
.scroll-to-reviews
{
    float: left;
}

.social-icons.share-row
{
    float: right !important;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.short-description
{
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted. Thanks!